# Updating an xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a python script that returns a list of tuples from an SQL query. I want to update an xml file I have with the data from the list.

What can I do to just write over a particular element or node with the list I received from my query? Thank you.

Ok, I am able to find the list of elements using findall() from the ElementTree, and it was suggested that I used setAttribute to update, which would work. However, what do I do about the possibility of inserting repeated data with setAttributes?

Let's say my xml contain a list of customers:

(customer name="bob", age="22")
..

I could use a loop through the SQL data, and use setAttribute add new data. But wouldn't that add an extra (customer name="bob", age="22) to the list if my sql data happen to contain that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module from the standard Python library. You can read the XML file, parsing it into a tree, then find the elements you're looking for, modify them, and write back.

If you have more specific questions, please ask.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the ElementTree documentation to find the elements that I was looking for within the xml document. I just have a question about updating concepts in general. For example, my sql query returns this set: <tom, 22>, <mary, 23>, <james 19>, ,<ed, 37>, <paul, 28>

Comment: @timtran: you can remove existing elements and add new ones instead, or change existing elements - whatever way is more suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

[python create xml and write to file](http://www.postneo.com/projects/pyxml/)
[the official document for minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)
[the official document for DOM](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html)
you can use `Element.setAttribute(name, value),Element.setAttributeNode(newAttr)` etc. to update

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the ElementTree documentation to find the elements that I was looking for within the xml document. I just have a question about updating concepts in general. For example, my sql query returns this set: (tom, 22), (mary, 23), (james 19),(ed, 37), (paul, 28). I want to update my xml file with this data. The xml already contain <customer name="tom", age="22" />, <customer name="james", age="18">. To prevent duplication, do I just do this update by deleting all the customer tag, and create a new list of elements to add them back in?